# Efficient code for the Ten True Sentences puzzle

Tags: programming, performance-tuning

I am trying to solve [Ten True Sentences](http://onepuzzleaday.blogspot.com/2007/09/ten-true-sentences.html) Puzzle.

> Take a look at the following sentences:
>
> - The number of times the digit 0 appears in this puzzle is _____.
> - The number of times the digit 1 appears in this puzzle is _____.
> - The number of times the digit 2 appears in this puzzle is _____.
> - The number of times the digit 3 appears in this puzzle is _____.
> - The number of times the digit 4 appears in this puzzle is _____.
> - The number of times the digit 5 appears in this puzzle is _____.
> - The number of times the digit 6 appears in this puzzle is _____.
> - The number of times the digit 7 appears in this puzzle is _____.
> - The number of times the digit 8 appears in this puzzle is _____.
> - The number of times the digit 9 appears in this puzzle is _____.
>
> Fill these sentences with digits such that all the sentences holds
> true.

I wrote the following code, but it didn't work.

```
Do[
  If[Tally[Range[0, 9] ~Join~ x][[All, 2]] == x, Print@x],
  {x, Tuples[Range[0, 9], 10]}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

How can I imporve my code?

**Updated**

```
Compile[{},
   NestWhile[Join[{1, 7, 3, 2}, RandomInteger[10, 6]] &, Range[0,9], 
      Tally[Range[0, 9] ~Join~ #][[All, 2]] != # &], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ][] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: This is because your puzzle is impossible. Every number appears at least once in your sentence, but you force us to use 0.

Comment: There is one solution in this puzzle, `{1,7,3,2,1,1,1,2,1,1}`

Comment: @VF1 The link OP provided also has the solution...

Comment: @Hypnotoad There is a solution because OP edited the question. Before, it stated that every number 0-9 should be used.

Comment: Isnt that cheating to use part of the known solution? Anyway this would seem to lend itself to a genetic algorithm, or at least track solutions that have been tried so you dont repeat.

Comment: The answer is all ones, obviously, because after the blanks are filled in it's not a puzzle! :-P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the finished puzzle will contain exactly 20 numbers, we can assert that the solution for `x` will satisfy `Total[x] == 20`. We can therefore consider the `IntegerPartitions` of 20, which are of length 10, and limited to the numbers 1-9:

```
parts = IntegerPartitions[20, {10}, Range[1, 9]];
```

The solution for `x` must be a permutation of one of these, so the complete candidate set for `x` is:

```
can = Flatten[Permutations /@ parts, 1];
```

There are 92278 of these, sufficiently few to use the OP's code straight away. However, we can also note that the solution must satisfy `(x-1).Range[0,9] == 20`, so we can further reduce the candidate set:

```
can = can[[Flatten@Position[(can - 1).Range[0, 9], 20]]];
```

This leaves just 391 possibilities for `x`, making the OP's code very fast:

```
Do[If[Tally[Range[0, 9]~Join~x][[All, 2]] == x, Print@x], {x, can}]
(*  {1,7,3,2,1,1,1,2,1,1}  *)
```

Answer (score 9):

Represent the solution as a list $\{z_0, z_1, \ldots, z_9\}$.  The counts of appearances of the various digits can be computed as

```
appearanceCount[n_Integer, i_Integer, b_: 10] := Count[IntegerDigits[n, b], i];
appearanceCount[z_List, i_Integer, b_: 10] := Sum[appearanceCount[n, i, b], {n, z}]
```

(This may be inefficient, especially considering the question will later be limited to one-digit answers, but I prefer it for its expressiveness and full generality.  Notice, too, the possible generalization to bases $b$ other than $10$.)

We seek a *fixed point* of the function that counts the appearances of digits in the answer and adds $1$ to each (to account for their appearances in the question itself):

```
f[z_List] := appearanceCount[z, #] & /@ Range[0, Length[z] - 1] + 1
FixedPoint[f, ConstantArray[1, 10], 20]
```

This starts with a somewhat arbitrary guess $z_i=1$ for all $i$. (I asked the iteration not to proceed more than $20$ times, to avoid infinite loops.)

> {1, 11, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

We need to check that this is indeed a fixed point (and not just the last thing that was tried):

```
f[%]==%
```

> True

The question does use the term "digit" to refer to what goes in the blanks, so perhaps the value of "11" would be considered invalid: it uses two digits. Rather than thinking too hard about this, let's optimistically start with some random guesses and check everything that emerges as a possible fixed point:

```
Select[Union[FixedPoint[f, #, 10] & /@ RandomChoice[Range[0, 9], {100, 10}]], f[#] == # &]
```

> {{1, 7, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1}}

One could systematically search for solutions by checking all $10$-tuples; there are $10^{10}$ of them, so this would take some time!

Comment: +1 for the fixed point method. btw there is a function `DigitCount` could do what `appearanceCount` does.

Comment: @Silvia Thank you--it seems like almost any one-line function I can write has already been incorporated in the software somewhere :-).

Answer (score 1):

too long for a comment -- but your basic approach does work in some reasonable time if we are a little smart about restricting the range of the values:

(either test works about the same)

```
test[v_] := Tally[Range[0, 9]~Join~v][[All, 2]] == v ;
test[v_] := Count[ v   , #] + 1 & /@ Range[0, 9] ==  v
result = Table[0, {9}];
Timing[While[! test[result] ,
    result = (Join[{1, RandomInteger[{5, 8}]}, 
    RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 8]]) ]; result]
```

> {68.5, {1, 7, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1}}

edit: again with a little less built in knowedge of the solution..
I think if you start working it by hand you'll quickly realise the #1's and 2 must be both greater than 2 and the others cant be too big..

```
test[v_] := Count[ v   , #] + 1 & /@ Range[0, 9] ==  v
result = Table[0, {9}];
Timing[While[! test[result] ,
  result = Join[ {1 , Count[#, 1] + 2 , Count[#, 2] + 1}, # ] & @ 
   RandomInteger[{1, 6}, 7]]; result]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = Table[{i,}, {i, 0, 9}];
Table[A〚i, -1〛 = Thread[Join @@ A == i - 1]~Count~True,
 {10}, {i, 10}] // Grid
```

Output:

```
1   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   9   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
1   8   3   2   1   1   1   1   2   1
1   7   3   2   1   1   1   2   1   1
1   7   3   2   1   1   1   2   1   1
1   7   3   2   1   1   1   2   1   1
1   7   3   2   1   1   1   2   1   1
1   7   3   2   1   1   1   2   1   1
1   7   3   2   1   1   1   2   1   1
1   7   3   2   1   1   1   2   1   1
```